# Antlr4 clearDFA golang

Tags: go, antlr4

I've been running into memory issues with a grammar I been working on using ANTLR4 and golang. I've seen a few google results saying to use clearDFA() to reduce the memory footprint, but it does not appear that that function is available in golang.  Does anybody know what the equivalent name would be in golang?

Comment: Calling that won't permanently reduce memory footprint. As soon as you start parsing again the DFA will be refilled again. It only makes parsing slower to clear the DFA.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce memory?  There isn't a whole lot of information on the subject when I do google search. Or some of the answers I do find, I don't really understand because there is not an example of what is being talked about.

Comment: The only way to lower the memory footprint is to use a smaller grammar. Memory optimization was not a design goal for ANTLR4, but ease of use and speed.

Comment: What does a smaller grammar mean?  I purchased the definitive antlr 4 reference book and I've done google searches and I don't really see much that explains(by giving examples) what things cause it to use so much memory(perhaps I am looking at the wrong term)?  I tried processing 500 files that were less than 50KB in size each and got to 5 GB of RAM before it stopped processing the files.

Comment: Smaller grammar means: less rules (but then it means to have a smaller language). Could be the Go target has a memory leak, however, if consumption grows that big. Maybe you try a different target language, like Java or C++?

Comment: I reduced the grammar by half and now it uses about half the memory and can actually process the entire 500 files without crashing.  Do you have any recommendations for how to re-write the rules to further reduce the size?